# How to change the order of words in a caption?

Tags: captions

I'd like to change the order of word in the captions of figures and tables. Instead of *Figure 1* , I'd like to use *1. ábra*. How can I do this?

Thank you in advance

Comment: It's easiest to use the caption package which has lots of options to change the word order, fonts, size, ....

Answer (score 8):

With `babel`, LaTeX does it automatically:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[magyar]{babel}

\usepackage{graphicx}

\begin{document}

\begin{figure}
\centering
\includegraphics[width=5cm]{example-image-16x9}
\caption{A caption} % Sorry, I don't know enough Hungarian
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: To the OP:  feel free to select this answer if you like it.